# Communication betwen Client and Servver running on two different machines using UDP Sockets in C using Visual studio 2008

Tags: udp, client

I have developed an application in which a client and server can communicate with eachother using UDP Sockets.
I have used loop Back address on Client side and INADDR_ANY for the Server Side. The program works fine on the same machine.
But when I tried to run the Client from a different machine, the communication failed. here is the code snippet:
**SERVER:**

```
    #define PORT 8888   //The port on which to listen for incoming data
   if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
      {
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

   ///Create a socket///
   if((socketIdentifier = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
      {                 
        //"Socket not created"
      }

   ///Socket Created///

   ///Prepare the sockaddr_in structure///
   serverSocket.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serverSocket.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   serverSocket.sin_port = htons( PORT );

   ///Bind///
   if( bind(socketIdentifier ,(struct sockaddr *)&serverSocket , sizeof(serverSocket)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
      {             
        //"Bind Failed"
      }

   ///Bind Done///
   if((recv_len = recvfrom(socketIdentifier, receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSocket, &clientSocketLength)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
      {
        "Could not Receive Data"
      }
 hDeviceContext = BeginPaint(AH_Glb_windowHandle, &ps );
                TextOut(GetDC(AH_Glb_windowHandle),10,10+i,receiveBuffer,recv_len);
                EndPaint( AH_Glb_windowHandle, &ps );
```

**CLIENT:**

```
   #define PORT 8888   //The port on which to listen for incoming data
    #define SERVER "58.65.172.11"  //ip address of udp server
      ///Initialise winsock///
       if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
          {
             //Socket Initialization Failed///
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }

       ///create socket///
       if ((socketIdentifier=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
          {
             ///Socket Creation Failed///
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }

       ///setup address structure///
       memset((char *) &connectedSocket, 0, sizeof(connectedSocket));
       connectedSocket.sin_family = AF_INET;
       connectedSocket.sin_port = htons(PORT);
       connectedSocket.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(SERVER);
       if (sendto(socketIdentifier,sendBuffer,strlen(sendBuffer) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &connectedSocket, sizeof(connectedSocket)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
          {
             MessageBox(NULL,
                        "Sending Failed",
                        "Failure",
                        MB_ICONINFORMATION);            
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }
```

Comment: Please Help me, I am waiting for response

Comment: I was using [what is my IP website](http://www.whatismyip.com/) to find the IP of machine on which Server is running. If the Client communicates on IP address generated by this website, the communication didn't work.
But when i used ipconfig command to find IP of Server's machine, the IP address i found was different from that generated by [what is my IP website](http://www.whatismyip.com/), and now when i tried to communicate from Client at Server's Ip address generated by ipconfig, the communication worked. 
can any body explain me how that happened?

Comment: Can anybody tell me? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can any body explain me how that happened?

Without looking at the code, I can guess that your [router](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_%28computing%29) is blocking the port.

First ..

> I was using what is my IP website to find the IP of machine on which
>   Server is running. If the Client communicates on IP address generated
>   by this website, the communication didn't work.

Cause that gave you the *external* IP address of your network. The one that is assigned to you by your ISP. Your router is sitting between your computer (or network) and the internet and blocking all external inbound communications by default.

Then ...

> But when i used ipconfig command to find IP of Server's machine, the
>   IP address i found was different from that generated by what is my IP
>   website, and now when i tried to communicate from Client at Server's
>   Ip address generated by ipconfig, the communication worked.

Cause ipconfig gave you the *local* IP that is assigned by your router in your LAN.

Routers, to protect their local networks behind them, filter all inbound communications unless you specifically tell them not to.

The first time when you tried to connect to the server, you used the *external IP* address, which the router blocked. The second time you used the *local IP* address you got from `ipconfig` which is fine since the router does not block those.

Here is a simple diagram ....

```
Client (local IP)--------
                        |
                     Router --- Internet (external IP)
                        |
Server (local IP)--------
```

If you want to access the server from anywhere on the internet, then you need to [forward the port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) in your router, so the server will be visible to the outside world. But be sure to secure the server machine, and your application, before opening it to the world.

If you are just testing or you will be using this server only inside your network, then just use the local IP. also, try to assign a static IP address for the server so you can use it in your code without recompiling your code.

Comment: I have a question related to broadcasting as well. you seem to know the answer, or atleast you can help me :( below is the link to my other question, kindly have a look at it if you can help me.
Thanks in advance
[Stack Overflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332023/braodcasting-udp-sockets-in-c-using-win32-api)
I really need help with that please?